# Gitlab download artifact of matrix job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am trying to download artifacts from a successful job.
The download for a regular job works but the download of of a job matrix is not working.

Any idea how I have to structure the URL for that.

```
lambda_build: [tools]
lambda_build: [helper] 
lambda-master works with ..../-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=lambda-master
```

I don't find answer in the gitlab documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a matrix job generates a name unique to that pipeline from each variable used, so I think you can't just use the name you gave the job alone.

For example, when declaring this matrix job:

```
myJob: 
  script: echo $FOO
  parallel:
    matrix: 
      - FOO: [bar, baz]
```

Gitlab will generate two jobs:

```
myJob: [bar]
myJob: [baz]
```

So you might have to put "build: [$lambda_build]" or something into the query parameter.